# Can reducing # of indexed pages increase professional keyword ranking vs. long-tail non-related rankings?

Tags: seo, google

I have a site that does social media analytics. We have many long term pages with analysis of social profiles (~18M indexed pages). We have a pretty good link profile, from many related & professional sites, and almost no links from problematic websites / spammy / adult websites. We're getting considerable traffic from SEO, but a considerable part of it is to shady content covering issues that are totally irrelevant to our link profiles, and many times to pages in languages we have no links in. We're also not ranking at all for professional keywords that are very related to our link profile, titles, descriptions, content, etc.

I'm not really sure why this is happening, because I believe all the right signs are there. I'm actually looking to avoid the shady traffic rankings (trying to also remove those pages from our site) and hope instead to get professional rankings. I was thinking of reducing the # index pages from 18M to around 500k. Do you think that can help? Can you help explain why we're getting ranking for things that are totally unrelated to our link profiles and not to those that are?

Comment: If you try and rank to much you will rank for nothing. Since your site is as you say, based upon social profiles, can you nail down your sites theme (keyword ranking across all or most pages) or is it really up to what you find?? I would warn about such a drastic change. As well, pages rank, lots of pages can really help to drive revenue, but only if they are focused. The biggest consideration is if you are trying to make money using Adsense and what your current metrics are??

Comment: Not using AdSense, selling access to a premium version, so looking to attract professionals in the field of digital marketing. If I understood correctly, your recommendation would be to keep the pages but make sure they are more focused on relevant keywords? Any suggestion as to how I can make the homepage / business-page rank higher for specific keywords? I feel the vast amount of pages are hurting them because when I compare to other sites with very slim and focused content and a similar link profile, they seem to be ranking well.

Comment: You are right. I was suggesting using semantics to your advantage by applying a theme of keyword usage across your content pages *in the content* so that they support the search prowess of the entire site. You can also trim useless content and keep valuable content- not knowing your site at all, this would be impossible to recommend, but you know a useless page when you see it I am sure. Figure out how not to create them or make them better or just not show them until they reach a certain level. You can also simply noindex, follow them.

Comment: The reason why I asked about Adsense is that page count matters during really slow times. Otherwise you have to figure out what is important to your users. I cannot tell you how to make two pages perform well without seeing the site/pages. But I can say stronger signals, title tag, h1 tag, description meta-tag, and other header tags can help, but also being thematically related to the site and each other/important pages, this can really help.